# Why does comparing these 2 dates fail in python when printed they are the same

Tags: python, python-2.x

I'm trying to compare 2 dates in python, when I print the dates they are the same but the comparison fails.

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print today
print '2019-04-30'
d1 = today
d2 = '2019-04-30'
if d1 == d2:
    print 'match'
else:
    print 'nomatch'
```

Totally confused why dates that look the same but the comparison fails.

Comment: Side-note: Python 2 hits end of life at the end of this year. If you're just learning Python, I'd suggest learning and working in Python 3; Python 2 is only for legacy projects at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not the same. You can test it out by checking their types

```
type(d1)
<class 'datetime.date'>

type(d2)
<class 'str'>
```

Printing d1 gives you the same string because datetime objects have a `__repr__` method that returns string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are comparing a `datetime` object and a string. For a valid comparisson you should parse `d2` using [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) and then compare:

```
import datetime
d2 = '2019-04-30'
d2_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now if you check for equality you will see that both instances are the same:

```
datetime.date.today() == d2_datetime.date()
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because python is a strongly-typed language. You're comparing string (d2) with a date object (d1). That's why they are not equal.

You can covert d1 to date `d1 = datetime.date(2019, 4, 30)`. That way d2 and d1 will be equal.

Answer (score 0):

Because one of them is string and the other is date format, and date format and string can not be same as value.

Answer (score 0):

you should do:

today = str(datetime.date.today())

Answer (score 0):

Both `d1` and `d2` are variables of different types, hence the comparison fails as below

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
print today
print '2019-04-30'
d1 = today
d2 = '2019-04-30'

#Both types are different, as seen below
print type(d1)
#<type 'datetime.date'>
print type(d2)
#<type 'str'>

if d1 == d2:
    print 'match'
else:
    print 'nomatch'
```

To compare them, make sure both are of same types, and then the values will be compared, for example the below returns True since both datetime string evaluate to the same datetime object

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('2019-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d')
d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('04-30-2019', '%m-%d-%Y')

print(d1 == d2)
#True
```